# Network photo viewer for Android

Tags: android, photography, image-viewer

I have a large collection of photos, all stored on my NAS (which works as a SMB/CIFS server). I would like to view these on my Android tablet.

So looking for an app with:

- can connect to a Samba/CIFS server
- interface for browsing, ie selecting a folder from a list, then viewing thumbnails for photos
- slideshow mode, to automatically change from one photo to the next
- caching/pre-loading the next few photos, to reduce loading time. It should not have a blank screen between photos.
- preferably free, but willing to pay a few £ for a good app

would also be nice to have:

- some  way of viewing photo metadata, eg EXIF, IPTC, XMP
- searching/browsing based on XMP tags
- playback of videos
- browsing and viewing photos from other sources, eg Flickr or Dropbox